# Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

Hi I was create one view and created one controller.
 I want to give validation to form input field using bydeault Laravel error but I m getting error

> "Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

My code of controller and view as follow:

index.blade.php

```
    @extends('app')

    @section('title','Services Page')

    @section('content')

    <h1>Welcome to laravel 6 Services Section</h1>
    <h4>lets do something better</h4>

    <form action="/service" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off">

        @csrf

        <button>Add Service</button>

    </form>
    @error('fname')  {{ message }} @enderror

    <ul>
        @forelse($services as $service)
            <li>{{ $service->name }}</li>
        @empty
            <li>No services Available</li>
        @endforelse
    </ul>

        @endsection
```

nd controller as follows :

ServiceController.php

```
    public function store()
    {

        $name_validate = request()->validate([
            'fname' => 'required'
        ]);

        $service = new \App\Service();

        $service->name = request('fname');
        $service->save();

        return redirect()->back();

        // dd(request('fname'));
    }
```

But I am getting error when form submit button not validate. 
Any issue with this code let me know. I am new learner in laravel

Answer (score 4):

Add the `$` to the message:
`@error('fname')  {{ $message }} @enderror`